# Improved Perlin Noise module for Lua

Tags: module, lua, perlin-noise

I need [Improved Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) in my Lua code.

Are there any decent open-source Lua C modules available?

Or is there any nice C library that I can write a wrapper for (perhaps with other noise functions)?

I know that it is not hard to write one myself ([reference code](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/) in Java is trivial to port), but I do not want to reinvent the wheel here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, well, I'll have to roll my own then: http://github.com/agladysh/lua-noise/